# If $|z-1|=1$, where $z$ is a point on the argand plane, show that $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=i\cdot\tan(\arg z)$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $|z-1|=1$, where $z$ is a point on the argand plane, show that $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=i\cdot\tan(\arg z)$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

**M y Approach:** Let $z=x+iy$

$|z-1|^2=1\implies (z-1)(\bar z-1)=1\implies x^2+y^2-2x=0$

Now, $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=\dfrac{x+iy-2}{x+iy}=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2-2x+2iy)}{x^2+y^2}$

$\implies$ $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=i\cdot \dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Now do I prove that $\dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2}=\tan(\arg z)$

**I know other methods to solve this problem. I Just want to know flaw in my approach.**

Comment: $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=\dfrac{x+iy-2}{x+iy}=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2-2x+2iy)}{x^2+y^2}$ How does the last step follow

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad I multiplied with conjugate of $x+iy$ in numerator and denominator

Comment: Shouldn't $\textrm{arg}(z)=\arctan\frac{y}{x}$...so $\tan\textrm{arg}(z)=\frac{y}{x}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=i\cdot \dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$ (for $z\not=0$).

Now you can use $x^2+y^2=2x$ again to have $\dfrac{z-2}{z}=i\cdot \dfrac{2y}{2x}$.